# Install contents of VM onto computer?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware, vmware-player, lubuntu

If I have a VMWare VM with Lubuntu on it, that I have customized a lot, can I install the contents of that VM onto a physical disk? I mean have it so that when I boot up my computer it will boot into my customized Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use a Clonezilla bootable disk and boot the virtual machine to this.

Then create an image of the VM using Clonezilla, making sure to store the image in a location you can access from the host.

Then use that same Clonezilla disk on the physical machine to copy that image to the physical disk.

You may need to update Grub, depending on how your disk and partitions are set up, but it should be relatively simple.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I would like to install it to another, blank, computer that is not my own.

Comment: Well, you'll need a place to store the image. But you should be able to boot to Clonezilla on the new computer. Perhaps storing rhe image on a USB drive, or on a network location both can access.

Comment: Can I make into some sort of installer disk that I plug into the computer, I go through a series of steps for installation, and my customized Lubuntu is installed on to the new computer?

Comment: There is ample documentation for Clonezilla. You will want to use it to clone the VM to an intermediate storage location, and then use it again to place that image on the target machine. It would be loads more work trying to build an installer for your personalize Lubuntu setup. Trust me, the image is the best and simplest method. Linux handles moving from (virtual) hardware to hardware transitions much better than Windows does, if that's what you fear.

Comment: I actually have one computer (a Windows laptop with the customized Lubuntu installed on it) and an old Mac Mini (which is my dad’s). I want to install what’s in the VM onto his computer. Can you please give me step-by-step instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question. My post answers your question as it is written. If your question is different, you need to make it so.